# Blazor <InputFile> showing invalid syntax error after upgrade from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 5

Tags: blazor, blazorinputfile

I upgraded peoject on .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 5, everything went successfully including updates of referenced packages. The only challenge I have is that on every component I have the Blazor InputFile tag, there is a syntax error highlight the whole input file tag.

```
[input file tag highlethed with syntax error][1]
```

I have search around web but seems not to have any leads.

Answer (score 0):

I later figured the InputeFile is also available in one or two other Libraries, so all I had to do was to fully qualify the BlazorInFile.InputFile

```
<BlazorInputFile.InputFile />
```